# Position elements around a half-circle (CSS)

Tags: css, positioning, geometry

Well, all i am trying to do is getting 7 circle icons around the top part of a half-circle. Here's a demo with only first 3 icons placed in order: http://jsfiddle.net/yxVkk/15/

That's how icon positioning is done now:

```
.one {
    left: -35px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

I found this way pretty complicated to arrange all icons this way and i thought there has got to be a better way of doing it.

I tried this method but it just didn't work: http://dabblet.com/gist/3864650

Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method from your link works perfectly.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tryzor/yxVkk/21/)

**CSS**

```
.circle-big {
  position: relative;
  height:180px;
  width:180px;
  padding: 21px;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  margin: 100px;
  }

.circle-big:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0 ;
  background: green;
  content: "";
  }

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px;
  }

 .one   { transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(130px); }
 .two   { transform: rotate(-50deg) translate(130px); }
 .three { transform: rotate(-70deg) translate(130px); }
 .four  { transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(130px); }
 .five  { transform: rotate(-110deg) translate(130px); }
 .six   { transform: rotate(-130deg) translate(130px); }
 .seven { transform: rotate(-150deg) translate(130px); }
```

Hope it's what you expected.
If you want to increase the distance between the big circle and the small ones just increase the translation.

Comment: well, i think there has got to be an error or something because that's all i see on the demo page: http://i.imgur.com/t5JDvZj.png

Comment: I didn't include the vendor prefixes. I added prefixfree. Should work now.