# Positioning divs in a circle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position 15 `div` elements evenly in a circle with a radius of `150px`. I'm using the following code, which seems to give an oddly eccentric ellipse that overlaps.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qt5uaz1/3/)

```js
// Hold a global reference to the div#main element.  Initially assign it ... somewhere useful :)
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var circleArray = [];

// Move a circle based on the distance of the approaching mouse
var moveCircle = function(circle, dx, dy) {

};

// Look at all the circle elements, and figure out if any of them have to move.
var checkMove = function() {

};
var setup = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    //create element, add it to the array, and assign it's coordinates trigonometrically.
    //Then add it to the "main" div
    var circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
    circleArray.push(circle);
    circleArray[i].posx = Math.round((150 * Math.cos(i * (2 * Math.PI / 15)))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].posy = Math.round((150 * Math.sin(i * (2 * Math.PI / 15)))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.position = "relative";
    circleArray[i].style.top = circleArray[i].posy;
    circleArray[i].style.left = circleArray[i].posx;
    main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
  }
};
setup();
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

});
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

First of all, the equation for a co-ordinate on a circle is simply:

```
(x, y) = (r * cos(θ), r * sin(θ))
```

where, `r` is the radius of a circle and `θ` is the angle in radians.

---

The reason why your code is creating an eccentric ellipse is because when you assign the `.top` and `.left` CSS values, you are not considering that it will actually take the top-left corner as its reference. I've fixed your code and now it creates a perfect circle.

#### Changes made to your code:

1. Added an array `theta` that holds all the angles.

   ```
   var theta = [0, Math.PI / 6, Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 2, 2 * (Math.PI / 3), 3 * (Math.PI / 4), 5 * (Math.PI / 6), Math.PI, 7 * (Math.PI / 6), 5 * (Math.PI / 4), 4 * (Math.PI / 3), 3 * (Math.PI / 2), 5 * (Math.PI / 3), 7 * (Math.PI / 4), 11 * (Math.PI / 6)];
   ```

   The image below shows all the angles I've used.

   [image]
2. Added an array `colors` that holds different colors.

   ```
   var colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'DarkSlateBlue'];
   ```
3. Made changes to your trigonometric equations.

   ```
   circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(radius * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
   circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(radius * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
   ```
4. Changed the way `.top` and `.left` are assigned.

   ```
   circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
   circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight / 2) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
   ```

   where `mainHeight` is the height of the `#main` `div`.

---

## [1] 16 `div`s

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdqq8ch/1/)

```js
var setup = function() {
  var radius = 150;
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
  var theta = [0, Math.PI / 6, Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 2, 2 * (Math.PI / 3), 3 * (Math.PI / 4), 5 * (Math.PI / 6), Math.PI, 7 * (Math.PI / 6), 5 * (Math.PI / 4), 4 * (Math.PI / 3), 3 * (Math.PI / 2), 5 * (Math.PI / 3), 7 * (Math.PI / 4), 11 * (Math.PI / 6)];
  var circleArray = [];
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'DarkSlateBlue'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
    circleArray.push(circle);
    circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(radius * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(radius * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
    circleArray[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight / 2) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
  }
};
setup();
```

```css
div#main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

## [2] 15 `div`s Positioned Evenly

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy8otm6d/5/)

```js
var setup = function() {
  var radius = 150;
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
  var theta = [0, (2 * (Math.PI / 15)), (4 * (Math.PI / 15)), (2 * (Math.PI / 5)), (8 * (Math.PI / 15)), (2 * (Math.PI / 3)), (4 * (Math.PI / 5)), (14 * (Math.PI / 15)), (16 * (Math.PI / 15)), (6 * (Math.PI / 5)), (4 * (Math.PI / 3)), (22 * (Math.PI / 15)), (8 * (Math.PI / 5)), (26 * (Math.PI / 15)), (28 * (Math.PI / 15))];
  var circleArray = [];
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'DarkSlateBlue'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
    circleArray.push(circle);
    circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(radius * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(radius * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
    circleArray[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight / 2) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
  }
};
setup();
```

```css
div#main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

## [3] Dynamically Position any number of `div`s on an Ellipse/Circle

The equation for a co-ordinate on an ellipse is:

`(x, y) = (rx * cos(θ), ry * sin(θ))`

where, `rx` is the radius along X-axis and `ry` is the radius along Y-axis.

---

In this case, the function `generate(n, rx, ry, id)` takes four arguments, where `n` is the number of `div`s, `rx` and `ry` are the radii along the X and Y-axis respectively and finally `id` is the `id` of the `div` that you want to append your elliptically arranged `div`s in.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55ukqboa/1/)

```js
var theta = [];

var setup = function(n, rx, ry, id) {
  var main = document.getElementById(id);
  var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
  var circleArray = [];
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'darkslateblue', 'coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod', 'olive', 'sienna', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'darkslateblue', 'coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod', 'olive', 'sienna'];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
    circleArray.push(circle);
    circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(rx * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(ry * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
    circleArray[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight / 2) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
  }
};

var generate = function(n, rx, ry, id) {
  var frags = 360 / n;
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    theta.push((frags / 180) * i * Math.PI);
  }
  setup(n, rx, ry, id)
}
generate(16, 150, 75, 'main');
```

```css
div#main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

### Edit[9th December 2015]:

[Here's](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/dPVbrQ) a more flexible version with start offset, clock wise and anti-clock wise functionality.

```js
/*
Usage: Position.ellipse(n, rx, ry, so, wh, idd, cls, cw);

where n = number of divs,
      rx = radius along X-axis,
      ry = radius along Y-axis,
      so = startOffset,
      wh = width/height of divs,
      idd = id of main div(ellipse),
      cls = className of divs;
      cw = clockwise(true/false)
*/

var Position = {
  ellipse: function(n, rx, ry, so, wh, idd, cls, cw) {
    var m = document.createElement('div'),
      ss = document.styleSheets;
    ss[0].insertRule('#' + idd + ' { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border-radius: 50%; box-shadow: inset 0 0 ' + wh + 'px ' + wh / 4 + 'px black; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); width: ' + String((rx * 2) + wh) + 'px; height: ' + String((ry * 2) + wh) + 'px; }', 1);
    ss[0].insertRule('.' + cls + '{ position: absolute; background: black; color: papayawhip; text-align: center; font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif; border-radius: 50%; transition: transform 0.2s ease; width: ' + wh + 'px; height: ' + wh + 'px; line-height: ' + wh + 'px;}', 1);
    ss[0].insertRule('.' + cls + ':hover { transform: scale(1.2); cursor: pointer; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }', 1);
    m.id = idd;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var c = document.createElement('div');
      c.className = cls;
      c.innerHTML = i + 1;
      c.style.top = String(ry + -ry * Math.cos((360 / n / 180) * (i + so) * Math.PI)) + 'px';
      c.style.left = String(rx + rx * (cw ? Math.sin((360 / n / 180) * (i + so) * Math.PI) : -Math.sin((360 / n / 180) * (i + so) * Math.PI))) + 'px';
      m.appendChild(c);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(m);
  }
}

Position.ellipse(20, 150, 150, 0, 42, 'main', 'circle', true);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);
 body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgb(198, 193, 173);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty complete, thanks! I am curious about your use of the slice method. I think I misunderstood what it's functionality is (I thought it related more to strings?)

Comment: `.slice(0, -2)` simply extracts, For example `500` from `500px`. You can use `.slice()` method on arrays as well.

Comment: Great post, super informative ! Forked Fiddle [5] with random circle numbers and diameters at http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7tkxj3/

Comment: can we do the same thing with elliptical shape?

Comment: This doesn't look correct, see the circle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3pgwcth/

The small circles are not aligned correctly outside of the big circle.

The x and y need to take in to account the size of the small circle, if we subtract 10 from x and add 10 to y we get a perfect position: http://jsfiddle.net/cL68os91/

Answer (score 17):

### Other approach without JS

chipChocolate.py's anser is pretty complete but there is an other way to achieve your aim. It is simpler and doesn't require JS.

The point is to think **"circle" and rotation** rather than rely on `[x,y]` coordinates :

You need to nest all the elements and apply a rotation to them. As they are nested the `n + 1` element will rotate according to it's direct parent's rotation. Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/xcyq50yv/)** :

```css
.circle, .circle div {
    width:24px; height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; top:50px;
}
.circle:before, .circle div:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.circle div {
    top:0; left:0;
    -webkit-transform : rotate(24deg);
    -ms-transform : rotate(24deg);
    transform : rotate(24deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

The diameter of the circle is controled by the height of the elements (in the demo `height:300px`) you can make that a percentage to make the circle responsive (see below).

The rotation must be set according to the number of elements you want around the circle. In the demo 15 elements so `rotation = 360 / 15 = 24deg`.

If you have a dynamic number of elements, you may use JS to add them and to calculate the rotation angle needed.

---

### Responsive example

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/xcyq50yv/3/)**

```css
.circle{
    position:relative;
    width:5%;padding-bottom:50%;
    margin-left:47.5%;
}
.circle div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    -webkit-transform : rotate(24deg);
    -ms-transform : rotate(24deg);
    transform : rotate(24deg);
}
.circle:before, .circle div:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; padding-bottom:100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid teal;
    background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to position them within javascript because I'm going to write code to manipulate the positions based on mousemove and need the script to be aware of their positions to begin with.

Comment: ok, I'll leave this answer in case someone needs the same thing without JS.

Comment: Great for me too. New native CSS capabilities may reduce the need to use complex javascript, so, when possible I prefer to stick to native instead of javascript. Nevertheless, huge amount of knowledge in the javascript answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution, based on ideas from other solutions I've seen

http://jsfiddle.net/0hr1n7a2/6/

```js
(function() {
  var radians, radius;

  radius = 150;
    
  var totalItems = 48
  var item = 0;
  function positionTarget() 
  {
    var x, y, angle = 0, step = (2*Math.PI) / totalItems;
    var width = $('#container').width()/2;
    var height = $('#container').height()/2;
    var itemW = 20, itemH = 2;
    var deg = 0;    
 while(item <= totalItems)
 {        
  x = Math.round(width + radius * Math.cos(angle) - itemW/2);
  y = Math.round(height + radius * Math.sin(angle) - itemH/2);        
        //console.log(x + "," + y);
     
  $('#container').append('<div id="'+ item +'"/>')
  $('div#'+item).css('position', 'absolute')
        .css('width', itemW+'px').css('height', itemH+'px')      
        .css('left', x+'px').css('top', y+'px')
        .css('background-color', 'blue')
        .css('transform-origin', x+'px' -y+'px')        
        .css('transform', 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)')
        .css('border', 'solid 1px #000');
     
        angle += step;
        ++item;
        deg += 360/totalItems;
     
        //console.log(deg)
    }
  }

  $('#theButton').on('click', function()
  {
        positionTarget();
  })
    
})();
```

```css
#container { width: 600px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid #000; position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Draw">    
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the position to "absolute". This will allow "top" and "left" to position the divs from (0, 0). Using "relative" will position the divs from where they would normally be laid out.
2. Change the center point of your circle from (0, 0) to something else, like (250, 250).

   ```
   circleArray[i].posx = 250 + Math.round((150*Math.cos(i*(2*Math.PI/15)))) + 'px';
   circleArray[i].posy = 250 + Math.round((150*Math.sin(i*(2*Math.PI/15)))) + 'px';
   circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
   ```

Comment: I want them to be positioned relatively from where they'd normally be positioned (which is the center of the page as a child of the "main" div, so they're all circling the center of the page, basically)