# Drawing objects in an elliptical perimeter

Tags: javascript

This question can be asked as a mathematical question, but mine is a programming problem.

I have a `List` of a certain number of elements (cluster nodes), unknown to me until I get the JSON data from server. I have to draw the nodes in "circle", so I need to compute `x` and `y` given the total number of elements for each iteration of the loop.

I know the `i`-th element will be phased at a `theta=2*pi*i/(n)` angle. So ultimately if I want to draw elements in circle I can compute each `x,y` as

```
x = r*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(theta)
```

where `r` is radius. For layout reasons (maximizing elements in a landscape-layout computer screen) I have to place elements around an ellipse, where radius `r` is between two radiuses, `r1` and `r2`.

How do I compute the coordinates given the `theta` angle, and `r1` and `r2` radiuses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning divs in a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle)

Comment: Sorry, that question is about **circles**, this is about **ellipses**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this has a minor change from my answer on [Positioning divs on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle/26601039#26601039).

First the equation for a co-ordinate on an ellipse is:

`(x, y) = (rx * cos(θ), ry * sin(θ))`

where, `rx` is the radius along X-axis and `ry` is the radius along Y-axis.

---

The function `generate(n, rx, ry, id)` takes four arguments, where `n` is the number of `div`s, `rx` and `ry` are the radii along the X and Y-axis respectively and finally `id` is the `id` of the `div` that you want to append your elliptically arranged `div`s in.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/uvv63vx2/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var theta = [];

var setup = function (n, rx, ry, id) {
    var main = document.getElementById(id);
    var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
    var circleArray = [];
    var colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'darkslateblue', 'coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod', 'olive', 'sienna', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'darkslateblue', 'coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod', 'olive', 'sienna'];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var circle = document.createElement('div');
        circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
        circleArray.push(circle);
        circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(rx * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(ry * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
        circleArray[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight/ 2 ) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
        main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
    }
};

var generate = function(n, rx, ry, id) {
    var frags = 360 / n;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        theta.push((frags / 180) * i * Math.PI);
    }
    setup(n, rx, ry, id)
}
generate(16, 150, 50, 'main');
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
}

div.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
```