# How can i build a circular dialog using css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Im building a mobile app using html/css to display a list of contacts. I want to display a shortcut to call/email on the lines of the attached screenshot. Any thoughts on how i could do this with css/html ? I have tried a couple of changes with JS for callbacks but havent been to represent the pop over.[image]

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I have added js code to create and inject div elements and call the html component actions to call/email and those work. Im not clear on how i can build this UX control

Comment: you mean the styling? give it a try and show us where you have a problem. we won't build it for you.

Comment: A square bordered div with half-width border radius produces a circle...

Comment: How can i build the overlapping circles ?

Comment: can you give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: For overlapping circles you would need to use `position:absolute`

Comment: I would put a wrapper div around the whole thing and then use margins to move the smaller circles. Can be done entirely with css. Create a fiddle and try it out. Remember you can use negative margins to move things around.

Comment: You could do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/yyort93s/

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes from my answer on [Positioning `div`s in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle/26601039#26601039), this is how you can do it.

The idea is to position the `div`s in a circle using Trigonometry and JavaScript.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy8otm6d/4/)

The function `generate(n, r, id)` takes three arguments: `n` - number of `div`s, `r` - radius and `id` - `main` in our case. If you intend to change the variable `r` other than `100`, you will need to change the variable `adjust` to make it align properly.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var theta = [];

var setup = function (n, r, id) {
    var main = document.getElementById(id);
    main.style.width = r * 2 + 'px';
    main.style.height = r * 2 + 'px';
    var adjust = 4.8;
    var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
    var circleArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var circle = document.createElement('div');
        circle.className = 'circle number' + i;
        circleArray.push(circle);
        circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(r * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(r * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
        circleArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2 - (n * adjust)) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight/ 2 - (n * adjust)) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
        main.appendChild(circleArray[i]);
    }
};

var generate = function(n, r, id) {
    var frags = 360 / n;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        theta.push((frags / 180) * i * Math.PI);
    }
    setup(n, r, id)
}
generate(4, 100, 'main');
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#main {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

div.circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

<sup>*Let me know if you need to make any further change*</sup>