# Calculating angles for a radial menu

Tags: jquery, css, math, geometry

I'm working with a copy of [a demo page](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index2.html). I've found out that the alignment of the menu items (`li`) is done using the `nth-child` pseudo selector and the `rotate` property. The problems I'm facing with the demo are:

- The number of menu items is fixed. On the page where I plan to use this, the number of menu items is dynamic because it changes from one user to the next.
- Its orientation is up to 180 degrees, whereas I want it to be a full 360 degrees.

In order to overcome these problems, I decided to use jQuery to count the number of menu items, then apply the appropriate `rotate` value to each item.

Upon investigating the CSS, I found that in the case of 7 menu items the rotation angle values are:

- -20 degrees for the 1st child
- 12 degrees for the 2nd child
- 44 degrees for the 3rd child
- 76 degrees for the 4th child and so on.

In summary:

> -20 degrees for the first child and keep adding 32 degrees for the next 6 children

Now I'm struggling to figure out the math behind it. I wish to calculate these values dynamically based on the number of menu items. What formula should I use to get the appropriate angles for each child?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work out the formula with a bit of algebra. Let's do it!

### Linear sections

Suppose we have a quantity `y` that we want to divide into `n` sections of size `x` that are separated by gaps of size `p*x`.

If there is a gap after every section except the last one, there are `n-1` gaps.

Thus, we have:

```
n*x + (n-1)*p*x  =  y

(n + (n-1)*p) * x  =  y

x  =  y / (n + (n-1)*p)
```

For example, if the quantity is 180 and we want to make 7 sections of size `x` separated by gaps of size `0.1*x`, we get:

```
x  =  360 / (7 + 6*0.1)

   =  23.6842
```

Now let's consider the total distance from the start of each section to the next.

If a section starts at position `t0`, the next section starts at position `t1` such that:

```
t1  =  t0 + x + p*x
```

To continue with the figures above, we get:

```
t1  =  t0 + 23.6842 + 0.1*23.6842

    =  t0 + 26.0526
```

Now we know that the section starting points are 26.0526 units apart and each section is 23.6842 units long.

### Circular sections

If the quantity that we're subdividing is circular, the calculation is different because the last section and the first section are also separated by a gap. In other words, there are `n` gaps in the circle.

Now we have:

```
n*x + n*p*x  =  y

(n + n*p) * x  =  y

x  =  y / (n + n*p)
```

So if we're dividing 360 degrees into 7 sections of size `x` with gaps of size `0.1*x`, we get:

```
x  =  360 / (7 + 0.1*7)

   =  46.7532
```

That's the size of a section. The distance between the starting point `t0` of one section and the starting point `t1` of the next section is:

```
t1  =  t0 + x + p*x

    =  t0 + 46.7532 + 0.1*46.7532

    =  51.4285
```

In summary, the distance from the start of each section to the start of the next section is 51.4285, and the length of each section is 46.7532.

Answer (score 1):

calculate the number of menu items.
so yo want to divide 360d between them.
simply by divide you understand each menu item degree

```
var each_item_degree = 360 / number_of_items;
```

you should add from fist child to last child `each_item_degree`.

it will gives you what you want, but without any margins. for margins between them yo can easily reduse total margins from 360,
 for example if for 7 item is 32d witch starts from -20 to 12, start next one from 15d. it gives you 3d margin.

good luck .

Comment: But in the example linked above, each item degree would come to `180/7 ===> 25degrees` each. But the degree applied to each item is `32degrees`. So why is there an increase of 7 degrees when the `margin-left` property of each item is `-10em`

Comment: dear @asprin it is clear that is not 180 degrees.. its more.. look more carefully.. the menu items cover more than half of circle...about 2/3...

Comment: @asprin the left margin is not relate to the effect at all .! inspect the menu items the remove styles you will understand what im saying.

Comment: You're right. Just one doubt. In the above example, if I use 50 `(360/7 ~ 51)` degrees instead of 32 degrees, the alignment is adjusting perfectly. I didn't even need to consider the margin each `li` is using. How is this possible?

Comment: @asprin. the reason : each li has the fix width  so the rest of space considers as a margin between them. try reducing and adding width...you will get understand .