# Mapbox GL js - Add multiple markers radially around a given coordinate

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, markers

[image]

As you can see from the image above on my Mapbox GL JS map, I'm trying to position the 'W' markers radially around the small '2' marker in the center but im stuck as to how to achieve this.

You can have a look at the fiddle ive attached below to better understand this.

But in essence, theres an array `w_markers_arr` and for each of array content, im adding a marker to the map, offsetting it a little bit from the center marker with the following code:

```
"coordinates": [
    center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0] - (w_markers_arr.length * 0.0006) + (i * 0.002),
    center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1] - 0.001 - (Math.sin(i * 0.001) * 0.5) 
]
```

I've tried playing around wiht `Math.PI`, `Math.PI/2`, to make it appear around the center marker but ive been unsuccessful.

In the current code ive attached, im trying with `Math.Sin()` to somehow make it appear in a wave (im lost tbh) but its unsuccessful too.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
#geocoder-container > div {
    min-width:50%;
    margin-left:25%;
}
.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder {
 display: none;
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl-logo, .mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-right {
 display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Set a point after Geocoder result</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />

 <div id='map'></div>


 <script>


 var center_marker;
  
 mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyaXNrYXNzaW0iLCJhIjoiSk1MaUthdyJ9.vkxtdDbYdLi524WwlKORBw';
 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
     container: 'map',
     style: 'mapbox://styles/fariskassim/cjmszx78b266o2rlar02ytynj',
     center: [127.017613, 37.591672],
     maxBounds: [
      [126.972368, 37.572532], // Southwest coordinates
      [127.073682, 37.629226]  // Northeast coordinates
     ], // Sets bounds as max
     zoom: 14.2,
     minZoom: 14.2
     // pitch: 60, // pitch in degrees
     // bearing: -60, // bearing in degrees
 });

 

 // After the map style has loaded on the page, add a source layer and default
 // styling for a single point.
 map.on('load', function() {

     map.addSource('single-point', {
         "type": "geojson",
         "data": {
             "type": "FeatureCollection",
             "features": []
         }
     });

  center_marker = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
       {
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
               "message": "Marker 0",
           },
           "geometry": {
               "type": "Point",
               "coordinates": [127.017613, 37.591672],
           }
       },
         ]
  };


     // create center marker and add to map
     var el = document.createElement('div');
     el.className = 'marker_places';
     el.dataset.index = 0;
     el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/seongbukgu/master/v2/img/icn/icn_marker_1.svg)';
     el.style.width = '25px';
     el.style.height = '25px';

     // add center marker to map
     new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
         .setLngLat(center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
         .addTo(map);


     /******/


     var w_markers_arr = ["w_marker1", "w_marker2", "w_marker3", "w_marker4", "w_marker5", "w_marker6",]

  var w_markers = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": []
  };


  // add w markers
  
  for (var i = 0; i < w_markers_arr.length; i++) {

   var w_markers_feature_toadd = {
                  "type": "Feature",
                  "properties": {
                      "message": "Work "+i,
                      "index": i
                  },
                  "geometry": {
                      "type": "Point",
                      "coordinates": [
                          center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0] - (w_markers_arr.length * 0.0006) + (i * 0.002),
                          center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1] - 0.001 - (Math.sin(i * 0.001) * 0.5) 
                      ]
                  }
              }


   w_markers.features.push(w_markers_feature_toadd);

      // create marker ele and add to map
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'marker_floaters';
      el.dataset.index = i;
      el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/seongbukgu/master/v2/img/icn/icn_marker_works.svg)';
      el.style.width = '35px';
      el.style.height = '35px';

      // add marker to map
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(w_markers_feature_toadd.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(map);

  }



 });





 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a circle with latitudes/longitudes can be quite tricky.

The library [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs#circle) provides some very useful tools, such as `circle` which returns a circle from a center point and a radius:

```
var radius = 0.2;
var options = { steps: w_markers_arr.length, units: 'kilometers' };
var circleCenter = center_marker.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

var circle = turf.circle(circleCenter, radius, options);
var circleCoordinates = circle.geometry.coordinates[0];
```

By setting the number of steps to the number of your markers, `circleCoordinates[i]` will contain the coordinates for each of your markers (+ the last one which is the same at the first one).

Here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/JmJbmQ?editors=1000

Comment: for anyone looking for an alternative answer. ive also managed to hack another solution using the method demonstrated here [9th December Edit]:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26601039/2805611